# What pixel is used from which band

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a code that is supposed to estimate the elevation (which is in percentile per pixel) where a certain value is minimal. I do this gridwise, but instead of using a grid, i want to use a reduced resolution image, with the value per pixel. I am able to find the minimum value (MOD_rp2) but am unable to link that for each pixel to the elevation band it originates from. How would I do this? Even better would be to link it to the actual elevation of that band, so the elevation for the corresponding percentile (from hgt_p)

```
//import Datasets
var MOD = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD10A1')
   .select('NDSI_Snow_Cover').filterDate('2000-10-01','2010-09-30')
   .map(function(img){return img.gte(40)});

//precentile list
var start = 5;
var end = 95;
var step = 5;
var percent = ee.List.sequence(start,end,step);

//elevation bands based on pdf
var hgt_p = hgt.reduceResolution({reducer:ee.Reducer.percentile(percent),
    maxPixels:15000,bestEffort:false}).reproject({crs:crs,scale:scale});

//create snow/no snow map (1 for land above percentile, and snow below)
var hgt_c = hgt.gt(hgt_p);
var x = function(img){return img.subtract(hgt_c).abs()};
var MOD2 = MOD.map(x);

// sum up all pixels which need to be minimized
var MOD_rp = MOD2.map(function(img){var rr = img.reduceResolution({
    reducer:ee.Reducer.sum().unweighted(),maxPixels:15000,
    bestEffort:false}).reproject({crs:crs,scale:scale});
    return ee.Image(rr)});

//minimize, to add: extract elevation from hgt_p which confirms the correct pixel)
var MOD_rp2 = MOD_rp.map(function(img){var a = img.reduce(ee.Reducer.min()).clip(C_A);
    return a;});
```

the full code can be found [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/56f00df14113ac8efaba658c86fb094a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of my supervisor, I found the solution
[which you can find here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/939400bf52401c7ba26dee5122bdb44e).
It was solved by transfroming the images with several bands, into singleband imagecollections, combining them and then qualitymosaicing. To do this for an imagecollection, the whole thing was put inside a loop.